# How to make JAXB xml array type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, jaxb

I am building an API, and I have tried with Postman create a new "`items`" and only accepts the the "`Items`" with like this: `<items type="array">`

My output does not have the `type="array"` that I want. I want to know **how can I make in java ou jaxb the `type="array"`** manually or not to my output (this is the code part that prints my xml output `jaxbMarshaller.marshal(invoiceRec, System.out);` ).

So **this is my output** right now is this, and my objective is to make this:

```
<items>
        <item>
            <id>1162842</id>
            <name>tatat2</name>
            <description>1</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>1163631</id>
            <name>testItem2333</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
    </items>
```

**I want to make it into this:**

```
<items type="array">
        <item>
            <id>1162842</id>
            <name>tatat2</name>
            <description>1</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>1163631</id>
            <name>testItem2333</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
</items>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**One of the solutions is very simple actually. I have just added without getters and setters.**

```
   @XmlAttribute(name="type")
    String type ="array";
```

**And it gives me the output with the `<items type="array">` and without the field `<type>array</type>` like this:**

```
<items type="array">
        <item>
            <id>1162842</id>
            <name>tatat2</name>
            <description>1</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>1163631</id>
            <name>testItem2333</name>
            <description>abc</description>
            <unit_price>1.0</unit_price>
            <unit>hour</unit>
        </item>
</items>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have my classes like this:

```
//ITEMS++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
    import org.hibernate.mapping.Array;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "items")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Document(indexName = "items")
    @XmlRootElement(name="items")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private Item[] item;

    public Item[] getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item[] item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "sum")
    private Double sum;

    @Column(name = "discount")
    private Double discount;

    @Column(name = "before_taxes")
    private Double before_taxes;

    @Column(name = "taxes")
    private Double taxes;

    @Column(name = "total")
    private Double total;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(Double sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public Double getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public Double getBefore_taxes() {
        return before_taxes;
    }

    public void setBefore_taxes(Double before_taxes) {
        this.before_taxes = before_taxes;
    }

    public Double getTaxes() {
        return taxes;
    }

    public void setTaxes(Double taxes) {
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public Double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }

    public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
        this.invoices = invoices;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Items items = (Items) o;
        if(items.id == null || id == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(id, items.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Items{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", sum='" + sum + "'" +
            ", discount='" + discount + "'" +
            ", before_taxes='" + before_taxes + "'" +
            ", taxes='" + taxes + "'" +
            ", total='" + total + "'" +
            '}';
    }

//ITEM++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.*;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.Objects;

    /**
     * A Item.
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "item")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Document(indexName = "item")
    @XmlRootElement(name="item")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Item implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
        private String description;

        @NotNull
        @DecimalMin(value = "0")
        @Column(name = "unit_price", nullable = false)
        private Double unit_price;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "unit", nullable = false)
        private String unit;

        @Column(name = "quantity")
        private Double quantity;

        @Column(name = "discount")
        private Double discount;

        @Column(name = "subtotal")
        private Double subtotal;

        @Column(name = "tax_amount")
        private Double tax_amount;

        @Column(name = "discount_amount")
        private Double discount_amount;

        @Column(name = "total")
        private Double total;

        @ManyToOne
        @NotNull
        private Tax tax;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
        @JsonIgnore
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
        private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Double getUnit_price() {
            return unit_price;
        }

        public void setUnit_price(Double unit_price) {
            this.unit_price = unit_price;
        }

        public String getUnit() {
            return unit;
        }

        public void setUnit(String unit) {
            this.unit = unit;
        }

        public Double getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public Double getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        public void setDiscount(Double discount) {
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public Double getSubtotal() {
            return subtotal;
        }

        public void setSubtotal(Double subtotal) {
            this.subtotal = subtotal;
        }

        public Double getTax_amount() {
            return tax_amount;
        }

        public void setTax_amount(Double tax_amount) {
            this.tax_amount = tax_amount;
        }

        public Double getDiscount_amount() {
            return discount_amount;
        }

        public void setDiscount_amount(Double discount_amount) {
            this.discount_amount = discount_amount;
        }

        public Double getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(Double total) {
            this.total = total;
        }

        public Tax getTax() {
            return tax;
        }

        public void setTax(Tax tax) {
            this.tax = tax;
        }

        public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
            return invoices;
        }

        public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
            this.invoices = invoices;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            Item item = (Item) o;
            if(item.id == null || id == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return Objects.equals(id, item.id);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(id);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + "'" +
                ", description='" + description + "'" +
                ", unit_price='" + unit_price + "'" +
                ", unit='" + unit + "'" +
                ", quantity='" + quantity + "'" +
                ", discount='" + discount + "'" +
                ", subtotal='" + subtotal + "'" +
                ", tax_amount='" + tax_amount + "'" +
                ", discount_amount='" + discount_amount + "'" +
                ", total='" + total + "'" +
                '}';
        }
    }

//And the code to convert the items+++++++++++++++++++++++ 

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput( true );
                conn.setRequestMethod(type);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset" , "utf-8");

                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Invoice.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
    //            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(invoiceRec, System.out);

                //TODO get of ITEM SET (DONE)-> -> Item[] item (DONE)->Items.setItem(item) (DONE) -> Return ITEMS to invoiceRec (DONE) -> Remove items -> !!Item need to hide TAX!!(it gets automatically)
                Boolean turOnTests = false;
                Item[] arrayITEM = new Item[invoiceRec.getItem().size()+1];
                int i =0;
                for (Iterator<Item> it = invoiceRec.getItem().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    Item f = it.next();
                    arrayITEM[i] = f; //GET ITEM into arrayITEM[]
                    arrayITEM[i].setTax(null); // !!SET TAX NULL!!
                    i++;
                    it.remove();
                }

                if(turOnTests)
                for(int y=0; y!= arrayITEM.length;y++){
                    System.out.println("TEST2: TOTAL arrayITEM[]: " + arrayITEM[y]);
                }

                Items totalItems = new Items();
                totalItems.setItem(arrayITEM);

                Set<Items> invoiceReturn = new HashSet<Items>(); //Set á Items
                invoiceReturn.add(totalItems);

                if(turOnTests)
                for (Iterator<Items> it = invoiceReturn.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                    Items f = it.next();
                    System.out.println("TEST3: Item on the invoiceReturn Items: " + f.getItem().length );
                }

                invoiceRec.setItems(invoiceReturn); //Return Items to invoiceRec
    //___________________________________________________________________________________________________

                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(invoiceRec, System.out);
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(invoiceRec, conn.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Advice1: XML markup will be visible in your text only if you enclose them between "``"s. Advice2: It is important to give to your question a clear, easily understable title. Your title looked before my edit more like a tag cloud, it didn't draw attention.

Comment: Thank you for the review peterh, i will be more carefull next time choosing a better title and making the content more readable. And use more special characters.